# Dependency injection of Abstract class and interface

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Can we do the dependency injection of abstract class and interface property into our desired class like below-given code?

```
abstract class Parent { }

interface Heritage { }

class Child
{
    @Autowired private Parent parent;
    @Autowired private Heritage heritage;
}
```

Comment: Sure, as long as you have some instances defined in you context. Abstraction is one of DI's [benefits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-containers) ([some more advantages wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Advantages)) after all, for decoupling, reusability, testability, maintainability, etc. Now if you could give us some more details about your case, we could debate whether what you're trying to achieve is the best way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the injection of dependencies using either Property Injection (a.k.a. Setter Injection) or field injection. Those practices lead to [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/). Instead you should solely use Constructor Injection as practice for DI, since:

- A constructor can guarantee that all dependencies are provided, preventing Temporal Coupling
- A constructor statically declares the class's dependencies
- Allows the creation of an instance of class without the need of any tooling (such as a DI Container) to construct that type
- When a component has exactly one constructor (which is good practice), it prevents the need to mark the class with any special framework-specific attributes, such as `@Autowired`.

When using Constructor Injection, the class will look as follows:

```
class Child
{
    private Parent parent;
    private Heritage heritage;

    public Child(Parent parent, Heritage heritage) {
        if (parent == null) throw new NullErrorException();
        if (heritage == null) throw new NullErrorException();

        this.parent = parent;
        this.heritage = heritage;
    }
}
```